# What do mathematicians call the Two's Complement on 8-bits group?

Tags: notation, finite-groups, definition

It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2^8},$ only difference is the symbols usually identifying the elements of the set are from $\{-128, \ldots, 127 \}$ and not $\{0, \ldots, 256\}.$

What is an elegant way to say this in math?

Comment: One says that one is using the *least absolute value residues*. Not a particularly elegant phrase!

Comment: It's also known as a *balanced* complete system of residues.

Comment: I heard the phrase *symmetric representation*, specifically, in the Maple command `mods` which represents $\mathbb{Z}_m$ using $\{-\lfloor \frac{m - 1}{2} \rfloor, \ldots, +\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor\}$ rather than $\{0, 1, \ldots, m-1 \}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group needs to satisfy the [group axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29), so you need to define the  group operation.  Presumably you are using addition modulo 256.  There is a natural correspondence between the two sets that takes $n \in [-128,127]$ to $\begin {cases} n+256 & n \lt 0 \\n & n \ge 0 \end {cases}$ and you can show that the group structure is maintained.

Comment: I think we're all in agreement that it is a group and that it's strongly related to $Z_{2^8}$.  The question seems to be what to call this group.